# Flask 400 Bad Request

Tags: python, flask, postman, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to post a question using the /questions api as shown in the code bellow. Whenever I try calling request.get_json() to try and see the body, I get this error in postman below. Does anyone have a solution ?

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, abort, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
import random

from models import setup_db, Question, Category, db

QUESTIONS_PER_PAGE = 10

def create_app(test_config=None):
  # create and configure the app
  app = Flask(__name__)
  setup_db(app)

 
  CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

  @app.after_request
  def after_request(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization,true')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS')
    return response

  @app.route('/questions', methods=['POST'])
  def add_question():
    print(request.get_json())
    return(jsonify({"msg":1}))
  return app
```

[image]

Comment: Are you setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` when POSTing?

Comment: Yes i did set the content type

Answer (score 0):

What is your Flask version? I would suggest you to update to latest Flask and try.

or if you don't want to upgrade try `request.json()` instead of `request.get_json()` ,

```
print(request.json)
print(request.json["email"])
print(request.json["password"])
```